# Dojo Cannot set href then select ContentPane in AccordionContainer

Tags: dojo, accordionpane, contentpane

I have two ContentPanes inside an AccordionView.  When a button is clicked on the first one I want to set the href on the second one and then set it as selected.  To do this I run this code:

```
searchResultsContentPane.set("href", "modules/content_panes/test_module.html");
searchAccordionContainer.selectChild(searchResultsContentPane, true);
```

For some reason though the ContentPane will animate it halfway opening and then it will just pop closed with nothing loaded into it.

Here is the ContentPane declaration:

```
<!-- Search Results Accordian View -->
<div class="searchAccordianPane" id="searchResultsContentPane" title="Search Results" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props='refreshOnShow:true'></div>
```

If I set the href inside the declartion as a data-dojo-props value it will show it but eventually I will need to add GET values to the URL so I can't have it static.

Thanks for the help